# If a continuous application $\phi:F \times T\rightarrow F$ is a contraction in F $\exists x(t) \in F$ such that$\phi(x(t),t)=0\forall t\in T$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

Furthermore assume that $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and is closed and $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$  is any subset. By being a contraction on $F$ I mean $\exists \lambda$ 0 < λ < 1 such that $\rvert \phi (x,t) - \phi(y,t) \lvert \leq \lambda \rvert x-y \lvert \forall x,y \in F$ and $t \in T$ then $\exists x(t) \in F$ continuous, such that$\phi(x(t),t)=0\forall t\in T$

It strongly reminds me of the fixed point theorem, then in these terms what it saying is that  $x(t)$ is constant for all t (thinking in the point of view of differential equations, there is a $x(t)$ such that $\phi (x,t)$ is its derivative) but I`m needing some help to understand how being a contraction implies that there exists a solution that is constant (is it even the right way to approach?) Can someone link other questions or sites on the internet?

Thanks.

Comment: `\times` will create $\times$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $\varphi_t := \varphi(\cdot, t) : F \rightarrow F,$ we see that we can apply the Banach-Caccioppoli-Picard Theorem (since $F$ is closed) to obtain the existence of a unique $x_t \in F$ such that $\varphi_t (x_t) = \varphi(x_t, t) = x_t$ for all $t \in T.$ Now let $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq T$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t \in T.$ We need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{t_n} = x_t.$ We have that:
$$\vert x_{t_n} - x_t \vert = \vert \varphi(x_{t_n}, t_n) - \varphi(x_t, t) \vert \leq \vert \varphi(x_{t_n}, t_n) - \varphi(x_{t_n}, t) \vert + \vert \varphi(x_{t_n}, t) - \varphi(x_t, t) \vert \leq \\
\varepsilon + \lambda \vert x_{t_n} - x_t \vert$$
for sufficiently large $n$ since $\varphi$ is continuous, so for these sufficiently large values of $n$ we get that
$$\vert x_{t_n} - x_t \vert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{1 - \lambda},$$
so indeed $t \mapsto x_t$ is continuous. I hope this helps. :)

P.S.: As for the existence of a function such as the one you described, I'm afraid it's not the case that it exists in general. Indeed, let
$$\varphi(x, t) := \frac{\lambda t}{2} x + 1 - \frac{\lambda t}{2}$$
for some $0 < \lambda < 1$ defined on $[1, 2] \times [0, 1].$ Clearly this is a contraction in the first variable and continuous function and its fixed point for fixed $t$ is $x_t = 1.$ Moreover, this function doesn't have any zeroes (for fixed t or otherwise), so this is why I assumed from the beginning that the statement proved above is actually what you might be looking for.

Comment: $x_t =1$ is a fixed point but $$\varphi(x, t) := \frac{\lambda t}{2} x + 1 - \frac{\lambda t}{2}$$ ia not the derivative of $x_t =1$. I got a bit confused by this example.

Comment: First and foremost, there is no reason to assume that $t \mapsto x_t$ is differentiable. Perhaps more importantly, how can a real function of two independent variables be the derivative of a function of a single variable? Regarding the question outlined in the first paragraph of your question, what I have proved above is probably all you can say for certainty about your function and the behaviour of its fixed points as I have pointed out by the counterexample I gave.

Comment: I think I got it. For any contraction $\phi$ there exists a fixed point  $\phi(x(t),t)=x(t)$, so I can put $\phi(x(t),t)-  x(t) = 0$ and call it $\epsilon (x(t),t)$ and set it equal do zero. I can separate $x(t)$ such that  $\epsilon (x(t),t) = 0$  which is the same contraction (not the same application) as $\phi(x(t),t)$, so to find an application that does for $\phi(x(t),t)$, what $\phi(x(t),t)$, does for $\epsilon (x(t),t)$ .

Comment: Anyhow, if my answer helped you, I would very much appreciate an upvote and accepting my answer.